# python file automatic running after saving in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is a very weried situation, in vscode, I edited my code in the root directory and saved it as test_distribution.py. After I run this file in vscode terminal. Everytime I edit and save this file, it gets run automatically.

So I moved this file to the subfolder of this project, but I found out it still get run when I edit and save this file. So I changed the file name to distribution_test.py and add logging and save this file again. It turns out it will still run when I edit and save this file.

How should I figure out why this is happening? What kind of info should I log out in order to figure out this issue?

As you can see the 1300000_bake.xlsx is generated by this python file, I even moved this python file to a different folder and changed the name of it as I stated above, I am very curious how to find out which program is running this

Pics as follow:

```
for store_id in store_ids:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for query_date in date_range:
    logging.info(f"提高计算速度, 使用常规kind_code_cate1类型")
    kind_cate1s = normal_cate1
    for kind_cate1 in kind_cate1s:
        for setting in [dev_setting, prod_setting]:
            eng = conn(setting)
            delivery_cycle = pd.read_sql(
                f"select delivery_cycle from dim_mty_goods where kind_code_cate1={kind_cate1} and can_be_ordered=1",
                eng,
            )
            delivery_cycle = np.unique(delivery_cycle["delivery_cycle"].values)
            delivery_cycle = min(delivery_cycle)  # 只有冷藏存在多个值, 1, 2, 3 取1, 其他均为单一值
            start_time = time.time()
            logging.info(
                f"开始计算, store_id: {store_id}, date: {query_date}, kind_cate1: {kind_cate1}, dev 环境: {setting == dev_setting}"
            )
            logging.info(
                f"bash command: {create_bash(query_date, kind_cate1, store_id, setting == dev_setting)}"
            )
            status = os.system(
                create_bash(
                    query_date=query_date,
                    kind_cate1=kind_cate1,
                    store_id=store_id,
                    dev_setting=(setting == dev_setting),
                )
            )
            elapsed = time.time() - start_time
            if status != 0:
                logging.info(
                    f'计算出现问题, store_id: {store_id}, date: {query_date}, kind code cate1: {kind_cate1}, 环境: {setting["db"]}'
                )
                break
            logging.info(f"返回耗时: {elapsed}")
            if elapsed < 60:
                calculate_time = elapsed
            elif setting == dev_setting:
                calculate_time = pd.DataFrame()
                while calculate_time.empty:
                    calculate_time = pd.read_sql(
                        f'select cal_time from calculate_time where dt = "{str(query_date)}" and store_id={store_id} and kind_code_cate1={kind_cate1}',
                        eng,
                    )
                    # 等待写库
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    logging.warning(
                        f"未查询到计算时间, store_id: {store_id}, date: {query_date}, kind_code_cate1: {kind_cate1}"
                    )
                calculate_time = min(calculate_time["cal_time"].values)
            else:
                calculate_time = elapsed
            logging.info(f"计算时间, {calculate_time}")
            arrival_sale_day = [
                "sale_predict_qtty_t1",
                "sale_predict_qtty_t2",
                "sale_predict_qtty_t3",
            ][delivery_cycle]
            dev_prod = int(setting["db"] == "marsboard_dev")
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
            while df_temp.empty:
                df_temp = pd.read_sql(
                    f'select store_id, dt, kind_code_cate1, {arrival_sale_day}, perdict_stock_qtty, predict_num, goods_id, goods_name from order_list where store_id={store_id} and kind_code_cate1={kind_cate1} and dt="{str(query_date)}"',
                    eng,
                )
                logging.warning(f"未查询到order list 里的信息")
                if pd.read_sql(
                    f'select store_id, dt, kind_code_cate1, {arrival_sale_day}, perdict_stock_qtty, predict_num, goods_id, goods_name from order_list where store_id={store_id} and kind_code_cate1={kind_cate1} and dt="{str(query_date)}"',
                    prod_eng,
                ).empty:
                    logging.info(f"生产环境本品类亦无数据, {kind_cate1}")
                    break
                time.sleep(0.1)
            df_temp["dev_prod"] = dev_prod
            df_temp["calculate_time"] = float(calculate_time)
            df_temp.columns = columns

            df = pd.concat([df_temp, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
            print(df)
df.to_excel(f"{store_id}_bake.xlsx", index=False)
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Added, as you can see it's still generating the file, everytime I edit and save this file, it will generate a new file by df.to_excel

Comment: Sorry, could you attach the screenshot of terminal?

Comment: the problem is that I don't even open one terminal for the vscode and it's still generating the file, I attatch my code in this file as well

Comment: Could you open your terminal to have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I avoid this issue by adding

```
if __name__ == '__main':
   fun()
```

I guess this file will be import or load or something else, then it gets run. Anyway, this is not important.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: This is a low-key answer that shows a really good way to deal with this issue. The backstory here is that when you import a module, python will run the code in that module. If you want to avoid having python run your code when all you're doing is importing it into a script containing your unit tests, then move the code in the script that would normally execute when you run the script into a function, e.g. fun(), and then add the code in this answer that checks to see if dunder-name equals main.

More background: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-__name__/

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
It's now fixed. To do my test I used [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/) and it was able to read my file when it started with `test_`. Because I'm stupid I named it a random filename `test_func.py` and in this one, I wrote "from main.py import *".
So when I saved, and used pytest to run my test, my main file was run too.

To fix this I just renamed my file in `teste-func.py` and it works.

Sorry my English is terrible. I hope my comment is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps , You have mistakenly installed an extension 'Run on Save' . I think that's causing the Problem.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer

Comment: no, I checked my extension, and the weired thing is that it only happpens for this file

Comment: Try Copying the Code and pasting it again in a different .py file.