# How to stop VSCode with python from running scripts "*_test.py" on save?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automated-tests

I have a folder in my vscode workspace with some scripts ending on "*_test.py" When I save any file, or do anything that triggers saving, the scripts are run. I did not have this before, I do not have any extensions like "Run on Save" or alike, and I did not configure anything (at least not consciously, maybe by mistake hitting the wrong keys). I did get an update of vscode yesterday.
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72688354/6619902) that addresses something similar in one of the answers, but it does not answer a general way of avoiding this behavior. I cannot change the name of the scripts, as I am collaborating.

How do I disable this behavior? or how do I search online for finding a solution to this?

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18305 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134941. check also the value of your `testing.autoRun.delay` setting.

Comment: Does this issue only occur in pytest or in all Python files?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Thanks for getting involved. It only happens with files that have "test" in their name, regardless where they are placed in my project. If I take out the name, it does not run. There is also no output in the terminal I have opened, so I only notice it if the script is plotting something.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I checked, and yes, for this to happen, pytest must be installed in the environment.

Comment: Read this [March release of vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_77#_finalized-support-for-continuous-test-runs).

Answer (score 0):

With the information given by the commentator @MingJie-MSFT, I was able to find the info needed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_test-discovery). Here the quick answer:

You need to change the value of `python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled`. Simply add to your `settings.json` file the follwing line:

```
"python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": false
```

Then [reload your VSCode window](https://www.graef.io/how-to-reload-vscode-window/):
Open the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and execute the command `>Reload Window`

This **seems to work only for each window/workspace**. If someone knows the general solution that controls the global behavior, I would mark that as the answer.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Yes, thank you for the reminder! I was hoping someone else might come with a "global" solution, i.e. making the behavior as a general setting and not per workspace. It might be that it is a trivial step, but I am not yet very well versed in VSCode.